# Converting to short type pointer?

Tags: c++, inline-assembly

I recently moved from inline assembly to high level language (C++) where I want to set the result from a `value^0x1A3C` into a short type pointer (WORD PTR) but I am getting the following error:

> A value of type int cannot be used to initialize an entity of type short*

I got the problem when passing an int type to a short*:

```
void PacketEncrypt(Packet* packet, int sizeofpacket)
{
    char* pointer;
    pointer = ((char*)packet+sizeofpacket) -2;
    short *pointer = packet->PacketSize^0x1A3C;
    packet->Type += 0x0FFF7;
}
```

What I want the compiler to make:

```
0041585E   8B45 0C          MOV EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+C]
00415861   8B4D 08          MOV ECX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+8]
00415864   8D5401 FE        LEA EDX,DWORD PTR DS:[ECX+EAX-2]
00415868   8955 F8          MOV DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-8],EDX
0041586B   8B45 08          MOV EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+8]
0041586E   0FBF08           MOVSX ECX,WORD PTR DS:[EAX]
00415871   81F1 3C1A0000    XOR ECX,1A3C
00415877   8B55 F8          MOV EDX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-8]
0041587A   880A             MOV WORD PTR DS:[EDX],CX
```

Comment: I think you might be going about this the wrong way - "I want my compiler to generate this code" is pretty arbitrary. A compiler can legitimately generate *any* code with the correct observable behaviour.

Comment: What are you actually asking for here?

Comment: i move recently from inline assembly to high level langs (C++) and i want to set the result from a value^0x1A3C into a short type pointer (WORD PTR) but i still getting the following error:

a value of type int cannot be used to initialize an entity of type short*

Comment: flexo i agree with you, but i want the compiler to generate the code "i know" its best; You just dont code without knowing how the output code will look like. I know compiler will choose the best optimization methods regarding opcodes, but i just set the assembly output as a reference for making it more clear.

Comment: In C++ don't try to think like an assembly language programmer - you'll just end up frustrated and annoyed at the language. It's much better to do what C++ was meant to let you do: focus on the bigger picture higher level things. In most cases compilers are far far better at generating sensible code in most cases than even really good programmers. If you force it to output something like that you'll possibly end up blocking other optimisations.

Comment: @user1175832: Don't pay to much attention to assembler code generated by your c++ compiler. If you write a huge program with hundreds of lines you won't be able to check what the whole output code look like. Trust your c++ compiler.

Comment: If you want to fix your compiler issue, cast using this : short \*pointer = (short\*)(packet->PacketSize^0x1A3C);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to write the calculated value to the location that `pointer` points to:

```
*reinterpret_cast<short*>(pointer) = packet->PacketSize^0x1A3C;
```

`reinterpret_cast` means "take an object of one type and force it into another type", and is the cast used to convert between pointers to unrelated types; the value is assigned as if `pointer` pointed to `short`. Note that this might cause undefined behaviour if the pointer doesn't have the correct alignment for `short`. In general, `reinterpret_cast` removes compile-time type checks, leaving the onus on the programmer to make sure the result is used correctly.

Comment: thats what i needed, can you give a little extra info about *reinterpret_cast*. I know the name says it all, but for the sake of learning, and by the way i didn't find the right words for describe my problem, so i guess the asm output could help somebody as a reference. Thanks again.

Comment: @user1175832: I've added more detail about `reinterpret_cast`.